# does apache camel-atom component supports basic authentication?

Tags: java, apache-camel, atom-feed

i was trying to consume atom feeds from a http url with camel-atom component, but it is giving 401 even when username and password is appended to url.

fyi- the url already has query params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, got this working...changed the camel version to 2.16..It seems only from 2.,16 version ,we have the support for basic authentication in camel-atom component